# How can I create a bot able to ask for multiple values in a single prompt?

Tags: machine-learning, bots, aws-lex, nlp

Imagine I want to create a bot to attend a pizza delivery service.
But I would like to handle if a customer want ask multiple ingredients like:

```
  bot: what ingredients do you want?
  user: please with cheese, mushrooms, and corn
```

I have tried AWS Lex, but a single intent can handle a single value per slot.

What framework and facility can I use to do that?

Answer (score 1):

I know for sure that aws lex does not support multiple slots in a single prompt. However, the same is possible in an utterance. I am sure lex will comeup with this feature (to capture multiple slots in a single prompt) in the coming releases.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like any framework that can handle multi-label classification can help with that. Alternativle try to train NER on these entities.